# Best way to securely save data on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, core-data, save

I am particulars talking about small (lest that 1 KB) data.
For example I have game statistics (high scores, and all other statistics, game played, won, ...) and I need to save it, but I do not want that user can edit (hack) that data.

This is workflow that I have so far is:
(there will be some code, because I thing that code is best explanation)

1. I make `GameStatistic` object, that is singleton.
2. When I call save method on it, it does following:

   1. `NSData* encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self]`
   2. `[encodedData writeToFile:[GTN_GameStatistics filePath] atomically:YES];`
   3. `NSString* checksum = [KeychainWrapper computeSHA256DigestForData: encodedData];`
   4. and then I save `checksum` in `KeyChain`

So basically I am using `SHA256` checksum saved in `KeyChain` as solution against messing with scores.

Can I somehow improve it?

I have never used Core Data, but I know that it have some kind of encryption.
Is it better to use Core Data with encryption or my current solution is better ?

**UPDATE**
NSUserDefault can not be answer.
NSUserDefault is basically just plist file in Library/Preferences.
So anybody can change it, for example user can use [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com), and change everything.

I am familiar with NSUserDefault and I use it just for data that I do not care if user is going to change it form outside of my app.
 Like for game sound setting ON or OFF.

Comment: could you explain your doubts about keychain?

Comment: @vikingosegundo I hove no doubts about it, I am just asking is there some what that is more simpler. Like Core Data with encryption ?